# How can I avoid opening the access and yet get report by ID in DoCmd.OpenReport

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, ms-office

I have the following code in a console app in C#:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport("My Report", AcView.acViewReport, Missing.Value, 'ID = 5', AcWindowMode.acWindowNormal, Type.Missing);

DoCmd.OutputTo(AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, Type.Missing, "PDF Format (*.pdf)", $"MyReport.pdf", false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint);
```

What I want it to do is NOT to open the report but produce the report based on the where condition I sent ... Is it achievable.. ?

I have a problem where I need to produce all reports for an mdb access database based on the IDs sent to it.

Also when this code opens it still asks for ID .. not sure why.

Comment: If this is in C#, then 1) an Access automation object must be opened to generate a report, but 2) the Access window could be set to remain hidden so that you don't see it.  However, you have not include the code where Access is opened.  The code you show does not include the Access automation object, so it is also not clear how you are calling DoCmd.  Is there a custom wrapper class?

Comment: How does it "ask for ID"?  Does the prompt say "Enter Parameter Value"?